# How to handle multiple title url for seo

Tags: seo

I am having multiple list of classes in my application. I'm trying to re-write a URL to every class for seo purpose dynamically.

Here is the rewrite url pattern:

Class title: Web developer with angular

Url: https://www.example.com/web-developer-with-angular

Everything is working fine if I doesn't have duplicate class names. If I got duplicate class names content going wrong.

How can I resolve this duplicate url issues. Can anyone help me?

Can I use titles like below for seo:

Class title-1: Web developer with angular

Url: https://www.example.com/web-developer-with-angular

Class title-2: Web developer with angular

Url: https://www.example.com/web-developer-with-angular-1

Class title-3: Web developer with angular

Url: https://www.example.com/web-developer-with-angular-2

Can anyone tell me, Is this pattern good for seo or not? Or Shall I need to maintain different titles?

Which is better for seo? Please help me and thanks for advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely keep different titles. /angular-web-developer, /freelance-web-developer, /professional-web-developer, and so on. The URL should reflect the contents of the webpage. For example, If the content of the webpage talks about a freelance Angular web developer, the URL should be something like : /freelance-angular-web-developer. A good starting point is to do a little keyword research using Ubbersuggest or Google analytics.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I understood why we need to use different titles. But In my case someone register and create their own classes. In that case rewriting titles of every class is huge task for me. Is there any dynamic process to do like what you said?

Comment: Let the user add a different class name if the class with the same name already exists. Please provide the application user flow or the language you are using so that we can provide more  precise information, thank you.